# Dimensional analysis of classical action

Tags: classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, action

Hamilton's action for classical systems has the units Joule seconds ($\rm J\cdot s$), which in base units is $\rm kg\:m^2/s$.

Does the $\rm m^2$ have anything to do with area?

I'm having a hard time "reading" the units here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not everything has a "nice" explanation in base units. Students often get this idea because a lot of things in introductory mechanics are explained this way ("acceleration has units of $\text{m}/\text{s}^2$, because it's the number of meters per second you speed up per second"). But this works only when you're dealing with very very simple quantities, like a ratio of length to time for speed.

In general you simply can't get an intuition for a general quantity only by looking at the base units. You're not missing anything here!

Comment: That’s helpful. I think I want things to be nice sometimes!

Answer (score 3):

It's not worth trying to interpret the units that way. To give another "what?" example, light intensity as power per area turns out to be kg/s${}^3$. What does that mean? Arguably, nothing beyond the more insightful W/m${}^2$. You can change the choice of base units in analogy with a change of basis for a vector space. It's probably more natural to use as our base dimensions those of $c, \,h$ etc. rather than the SI units, which are a historical accident. On this view, action has dimension $h^1$.

Comment: I don’t know enough about using the “natural” units. Can you recommend a thing to read about it?

Comment: @crastinus Start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units

Answer (score 3):

The dimensions of action are generally best understood in the light of a concept known as [canonically conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables) pairs of variables. These are important when you formalize newtonian mechanics using the [lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) and [hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) formalisms of [analytical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_mechanics), as well as for quantum mechanics.

Basically, the concept of a conjugate pair of variables is essential to the formulation of the fully-grown equations of motion as [Hamilton's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Overview), as well as to providing a natural geometric structure that underpins classical mechanics, via an operation known as the [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket). However, knowing what conjugate pairs actually are and do isn't all that important if what you want is a nice look at the dimensionality of action $-$ they're just great at providing nice ways to slice $S$.

So, let me put up some examples. Action has dimensions of $[S] = [M L^2/T]$, and this can be thought of as the products of:

- position $[x]=[L]$ and momentum $[p] = [ML/T]$
- energy $[E] = [ML^2/T^2]$ and time $[t]=[T]$
- angular momentum $[l] = [L\times ML/T] = [ML^2/T]$ and angle $[\theta]=[1]$
- electric vector potential $[A] = [ML/TQ]$ and electric dipole moment $[d]=[QL]$

The fact that the first two examples crop up [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) is, of course, no coincidence.

If you absolutely insisted on interpreting the $L^2$ as a single grouping, then the thing to do would be to find a system that was well characterized by a [generalized coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) with dimensions of area, which would then have a conjugate (vaguely related to surface tension) with dimensions $[M/T]$, though of course that's pretty contrived.

Comment: Fascinating! I did find the examples helpful too. I see what you mean about how contrived it would be.

Answer (score 0):

Actually maybe the simplest thing to do is to think of Joules as energy, i.e. having the same units as $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$.  Clearly here the unit of length is not related to the area, but simply to the fact that energy scales likes the displacement squared.  You can multiply everything by $s$ without affecting the argument and correctly get kg$\cdot$m$^2$s.

Comment: I don’t think I follow.

Comment: @crastinus   the $m^2$ in the unit “Joules” does not refer to area but comes from velocity square, which has noting to do with area but with displacement squared.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I think I'm too stuck on thinking of units really as just aspects of the quantities that I think I know, like velocity, and not in the more correct way yet.